# The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, CarouselDataItem)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm getting an error in eclipse stating

```
"The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, CarouselDataItem)"
```

How might this be avoided? I'm attempting to implement an image carousel in Android and I cannot seem to avoid this issue. I've tried changing the type of docu to boolean - however that simply causes more issues.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
         CarouselDataItem docu =  (CarouselDataItem) m_carouselAdapter.getItem((int) arg3);

            Intent intent = null;

            if (docu .equals("John F. Kennedy"))
                intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Audio.class);
            if (docu .equals("Lyndon B. Johnson"))
                intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Video.class);
            if (docu .equals("Richard Nixon"))
                intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Photos.class);
            if (docu .equals("Gerald Ford"))
                intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Written.class); 
            if (intent != null) {
                intent.putExtra("KEY", docu );
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

}
```

Comment: implement Parcelable interface to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

You're attempting to pass custom Object through Activity. In this case any kind of Object that  you want to pass between Activities has to implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Serializable is easier to implement but Parcelable is officially recommended. More information you can find [in this thread](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing-object-by-intent-serializableparcelable.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call putExtra with docu, since docu is of type CarouselDataItem and there exist no method in Intent named putExtra with parameters String and CarouseldataItem. Instead, let CarouselDataItem extend Parcelable which enables it to be sent among activities.

See [this blogpost about parcelable](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/) for good examples.